# How do I change the property of one type of Child Controls in a form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, controls

In a VB **WindowsForms** Application,

I want to change the value of *many* DomainUpDown controls which are *inside a GroupBox* Control or a Panel.

[image: What to Change]

I though of a short code.

```
For Each item As DomainUpDown In GroupBox1.Controls
        item.Value = 0
Next
```

But Shows me error, "Value' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DomainUpDown'.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DomainUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.domainupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have any property like `Value` This control will perform same as `ComboBox`. There are several property that you can assign to change the value.

```
item.Text = "0"

Dim iIndex As Integer = 0
item.SelectedIndex = iIndex   //SelectedIndex will have integer type value

item.SelectedItem = "0"  //SelectedItem will have object type value
```