# Is their any CharacterUpDown Control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, numericupdown

In VB Win-forms Application a NumericUpDown Control is used for only to scroll numbers. Its definition is:

The Windows Forms NumericUpDown control looks like a combination of a text box and a pair of arrows that the user can click to adjust a value. The control displays and sets a single **numeric value from a list of choices**. As Shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/729xt55s(v=vs.90).aspx).

I want to **use strings instead of numeric values**. For example, Grades: "A","B","C", etc. I think I will need to use UserContorl to code another custom "StringUpDown" Control.

Comment: I find it very strange that you ask this question as you [obviously know the existence of the DomainUpDown control.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350634/how-do-i-change-the-property-of-one-type-of-child-controls-in-a-form).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add String values to `Numeric Drop down`. instead for this you can use [DomainUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.domainupdown.items(v=vs.110).aspx) here is the code to place a `DomainUpDown` in your form that contains `A - Z` characters

```
    Dim domainUpDown1 As DomainUpDown
    domainUpDown1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DomainUpDown()
    For i As Integer = 65 To 90
        domainUpDown1.Items.Add(Chr(i))
    Next
    Controls.Add(domainUpDown1)
```

**Note :** This control is available in `Tool box` also

Answer (score 0):

You can change values using the ByRef=""

e.g. RefValues="Red;Blue;Green;Brown"

Hope this is what you were looking for

Link: [mindStick](http://www.mindstick.com/Beginner/5C2FEF23-3DAD-4A51-8196-8499CA23DCB8/AJAX/Ajax%20Toolkit%20NumericUpDownExtender%20Control%20in%20ASP%20Net/)

Comment: Question was tagged WinForms.